# how to create a service, that would be listening to the volume button?

Tags: android

I need to create a service that would be running in the background, displaying an icon in the notification bar, listen to the volume buttons being presses and prevent them from changing the volume, so that annoying beep won't be heard.

What do you think, is that possible? And if yes, where should I start?

Thanks!

edit:

found this snippet that works great for an activity, now will have to try it with a service.

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    int action = event.getAction();
    int keyCode = event.getKeyCode();
        switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP:
            if (action == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "UP", 1500).show();
            }
            return true;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN:
            if (action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "DOWN", 1500).show();
            }
            return true;
        default:
            return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
        }
    }
```

edit2:
found a nice tutorial over here http://android.kgmoney.net/2010/05/08/creating-a-simple-android-service-for-background-processing/

created a service, but the above code doesn't seem to fit into it... hmm...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What do you think, is that possible?

No. You cannot listen for volume button presses in a service.

Comment: Yes, as I learned, unfortunately its so. Do you think there might be other ways for a user to pass a signal to a service, other then by the means of an activity. Maybe a widget can listen to a volume button, and then pass it to a service?

Comment: @user296516: Only the foreground activity can intercept volume button presses.

Comment: @CommonsWare how to solve this problem. Is there any workarround ?